# how to reduce the coutdown size in flutter

Tags: flutter, countdown, flutter-widget

I am stuck in the case where I have to implement a timer for One Time Password reset. so I have used this code

```
Countdown(
                                    animation: StepTween(
                                      begin: levelClock,
                                      end: 0,
                                    ).animate(_controller),
                                  ),
```

and the output came as like this [image]

how can I reduce the size of the timer to normal size as the words size? I have wrapped the countdown widget with a container but still it is not working.